# Booting from Ubuntu install disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot

My dilemma continues.  I had copied the latest Ubuntu download to DVD.  Reason being, I don't have enough space on my dual partition drive so need to start fresh.  From Ubuntu I did a restart with that DVD in the optical drive expecting it would start the process.  It just by-passed the DVD and went right to my dual boot menu and then into Ubuntu as it currently exists on my drive.  Do I need to do a shut down for this DVD to start the formating and new install?

Comment: Your boot order is set to boot from your hard drive first, and the DVD secondly. You can usually fix this in your BIOS, but exactly how you do this depends on your machine.

Comment: You say copy which you cannot do as then it is not bootable, just data. You have to use an installer. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Comment: Ok, so I went through the steps you said.  The file I was about to download is the same one I already have so I canceled that., just under a gig.  I do have a file on my DVD I burned yesterday called linuxiso

Comment: Also, the files I downloaded yesterday is called ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to boot from a USB stick using this http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/ 
Sometimes it requires to download a couple of times the ISO to burn it without any faults.